# unknown database type .db .idx .lck?

Tags: database

Does anyone know what is the database type of this ?

http://ge.tt/2Qe7PvL2/v/0

and if its possible to migrate to sql or csv ?

Comment: could it be a 'paradox' database...Have you tried doing a 'hex edit' of the files? They often have 'useful information' that the application can use to determine that the files are correct. Such as 'file type' and version number'.  Hmm... more details required such as 'operating system', directory path names, the age of the database and what it was type of application it came from would be useful. There are way too many possibilities currently.

Comment: no info in HEX. OS is Linux, Database is 18 years old give or take 2 years. and the type of application I actually dont know. its a web application and the extension is .bp

Answer (score 0):

`.db` files are typically [sqlite](/questions/tagged/sqlite) files, and you should use that program to execute it. `.lck` usually means a lock file, which a program uses to indicate that it is taking charge of some resource in order to prevent multiple programs (or multiple instances of the same program) from handling it. It usually won't make to much sense attempting to "recover" it.

Comment: i tried to open in sqlite it gave me "invalid format"